# how to add mouseover tooltip in charts c#

Tags: c#, charts

I want to show some information(value of column `'a'`) retrieving from data base when user hover mouse on the bar line. here is my code for displaying chart in C#. Please help

```
var query="select a,b,c from abc";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
Chart1.Series.Add("test");
Chart1.Series["test"].XValueMember = "a";
Chart1.Series["test"].YValueMembers = "b";
Chart1.DataSource = dt;
Chart1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You can add a Tooltip [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687(v=vs.100).aspx) to the Chart or add indiviual ToolTips to each DataPoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

`chart1.Series["test"].ToolTip = "Y Value: #VALY";`

For more controlled jquery tooltip, trying some like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/465155/Simple-Chart-with-ToolTip-using-ASP-NET-Chart-Cont)

Comment: It is printing this "Y Value: a" on mouse hover over a bar line

Comment: I'm sorry it's `#VALY`, I updated the answer as well.

Comment: It's just #VAL for Y axis values and #VALX for X-Axis